# Program that Encrypts and Decrypts a text file

Tags: python, text

My sample text file is: 'abcd abcd abcd'

The program has a dictionary with symbols dedicated for each letter. The objective is to create a new file with the files message encrypted.

Program 'works'. By this I mean that it only converts abc. Since theres no d in the dictionary then it raises an error. I removed the d and tried again, but this raises another error called: *KeyError: ' '*

How can I make my program detect spaces, and write the letter even if theres no symbol for it?

```
def main():
    ecrypt = {'a':'%', 'b':'&', 'c':'/'}
    input_file = open('efile.txt', 'r')
    output_file = open('newefile.txt', 'w')
    line = input_file.readline()
    for letter in line:
        if letter in line:
            output_file.write(ecrypt[letter])            

main()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `try-except` for handle the `KeyError` but as a more pythonic way you can use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) function that is actually for this aim  :

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> i='abc'
>>> o='%&/'
>>> trantab = maketrans(i, o)

>>> print 'abcd abcd abcd'.translate(trantab)
%&/d %&/d %&/d
```

and for translate the file and write in another file  :

```
from string import maketrans
i='abc'
o='%&/'
trantab = maketrans(i, o)
with open('efile.txt', 'r') as infile,open('newefile.txt', 'w') as out :
    out.write(infile.read().translate(trantab))
```

Comment: Well the thing is It needs to read the contents from a file. Will it work if I asign the contents of the file to the i variable? And then asign the translation to an output_file?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to access ecrypt['d'] which doesn't exist. With this current code, you'd need to make sure every character (not just letter, punctuation... Spaces...) is in the ecrypt dict.

I suggest adding an exception. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html
The 'if letter in line' is superfluous.

```
for letter in line:
        try:
             output_file.write(ecrypt[letter])           
        except KeyError:
             output_file.write(letter)
```

Or, test that the letter exists first.

```
for letter in line:
    cipher_letter=ecrypt[letter] if letter in ecrypt else letter       
    output_file.write(cipher_letter)
```

Comment: I'd use str.translate as Kasra suggests, but hopefully this helps you see how the current code could be fixed and learn a bit about Python.